# Single Login for multiple platforms on different websites

Tags: php, mysql, openid

I have a network with at least two platforms which are hosted on different servers/websites.

```
- Platform A
- Platform B
```

Each platform has a user database with usernames and passwords. Each user has an account on each platform. However the encryption algorithm and salt keys differs between the platforms.

I'm looking for a solution for the following:

A user logs into Platform A with his username and password. Then a link allows him to auto-login on Platform B without logging in again. Also the opposite direction should work.

First I had the idea to implement a special token submitted via GET or POST. But this would be a security vulnerability if someone else reads the HTML source code while the user is logged in. He could copy the token and use it from somewhere else.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613655/implementing-a-single-login-for-three-websites-in-php), but it seems to aim for another scenario with a common user database.

Is there another solution without implementing OpenID services, that allows a secure single-login via tokens?

Comment: You're looking for something like [OAuth](http://oauth.net/2/). Or possibly OAuth itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to implement some logic on the login scripts on both servers?
Perhaps you could implement a call sharing the login action between the two platforms on succesfull login?

say: Platform A logs in.
- Credentials are valid.
- API/REST call to platform B given the username.
- Platform B sents back a hash you can use to authenticate user on Platform B.
- You need to create a redirect location on Platform B for platform A to sent user in using that hash and authenticate the user are being the user you think it is on Platform B (match the hash to the e-mailadress of perhaps user id.)